# Persist multiple entities in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I cannot persist multiple entities inside the controller. I can only save the last one.

My code:

```
$product = new Product();
$names = ['yellow', 'blue', 'red']; // save these to the table

foreach ($name as $name) {
    $product->setName($name);
    $em->persist($product);
    // $em->flush(); // doesn't work either
}

 $em->flush();
```

I am using Symfony 2.7

Answer (score 7):

You have to create a new Product inside your loop.
Right now it's only taking 1 product, and it's constantly updating that one.

```
$names = ['yellow', 'blue', 'red']; // save these to the table

foreach ($names as $name) {
    $product = new Product();
    $product->setName($name);
    $em->persist($product);
}

$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 2):

I created this solution which looks nice:

```
array_walk($arrayOfEntities, function ($entity) {
   $entityManager->persist($entity); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **clone** operator (php 5+)

```
$product = new Product();
$names = ['yellow', 'blue', 'red'];

foreach ($names as $name) {
    $tmpProductObj = clone $product;
    $em->persist($tmpProductObj);
}

$em->flush();
```

More information about cloning an object can be found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Answer (score -1):

You are only creating one Object Product.
Obviously, only one object will be persisted to the database then.
Also at the top your variable is called `$Product`(capital P) while in the loop it is called `$product`.

Try this instead:

```
$NameList = array("yellow","blue","red"); // save these to the table

foreach($NameList as $name){
  $product = new Product();
  $product->setName($name);
  $em->persist($Product);
  //$em->flush(); // doesnot work either
 }

 $em->flush();
```

Answer (score -1):

If I want add multiple objects after set its value I use clone in loop:

```
        $application = new Application();
        $application->setSomething($someting);

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $request->get('number_of_applications'); $i++){
            $applicationObj = clone $application;
            $em->persist($applicationObj);
        }
        $em->flush();
```